# How can I use the standard computer modern font while still using the Fourier package symbols?

Tags: fonts, fourier

I am using the Fourier package in order to have access to its symbols, but it changed the fonts in my document. I wish to be able to use its symbols while maintaining the standard font I had previously. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Generally impossible, because the `fourier` package changes the tables of math symbols. Besides, many of the `fourier` symbols are visually incompatible with Computer Modern. Can you be more specific about what symbols you need?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> There is a new package provided with Fourier-GUT
>   enberg: `fourier-orns`.
>   This is for those who want only the Fourier-GUT
>   enberg
>   logos & decos, but not
>   the Fourier-GUT
>   enberg
>   fonts.
>   Please don’t call it if you call
>   `fourier`.

So it's just

```
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
```

And you're ready to go.